# Adding working days to date in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to add working days only to a date column and skip weekend days (Saturday & Sunday) in Excel power query

I have a "date" column & a column with "transit days", my intention is to add working days only to the date column

take the date as 21st of April 2023 and add 5 working days, the answer should be 28th of April 2023 using the power query

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can try this in powerquery.

If you don't care about holidays, or making sure the starting date is also a working date, then just use this, which simply adds a few days then checks to see if that's on a Saturday or Sunday, which it then moves to the Monday

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Next Working Day", each if Date.DayOfWeek(Date.AddDays([Date],[Add Days])) = 6 then Date.AddDays([Date],[Add Days]+2) else if Date.DayOfWeek(Date.AddDays([Date],[Add Days])) = 0 then  Date.AddDays([Date],[Add Days]+1) else Date.AddDays([Date],[Add Days]),type date)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

**ALTERNATIVE**

If you want to omit a list of holidays and/or make sure that the starting date is also a working date and not a holiday, you can use this

```
//First Working Day = first Working Date equal to or after Date
//Next Working Day = first Working Date equal to or after (Date + Add Days)
//Next Working Day2 = first Working Date equal to or after (First Working Day + Add Days)
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
holidays = {#date(2012,10,10),#date(2012,10,15),#date(2012,11,18)}, // list of holidays to skip
DateList = List.Dates(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Date]), Duration.Days(List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Date]) -List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Date])) +365 ,#duration(1,0,0,0)),
DateList2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.FromList(List.Transform(List.RemoveItems(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform( DateList ,each if Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday)>4 then null else _)),holidays), each Date.ToText(_))),{{"Column1", type date}}), //table of weekdays excluding holidays
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "First Working Day", (i)=> Table.SelectRows(DateList2, each [Column1]>=  i[Date]){0}[Column1],type date),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Next Working Day", (i)=> Table.SelectRows(DateList2, each [Column1]>=  Date.AddDays(i[Date],i[Add Days])){0}[Column1],type date),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Next Working Day2", (i)=> Table.SelectRows(DateList2, each [Column1]>=  Date.AddDays(i[First Working Day],i[Add Days])){0}[Column1],type date)
in #"Added Custom3"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For adding a single working day you can use https://gorilla.bi/power-query/next-working-day/ that shows:

```
  List.Generate(
   () => Date.AddDays( [Date], 1 ),         // start value is date + 1
   each Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday) >= 5, // if date falls in weekend
   each Date.AddDays(_, 1)                  // generate date of the next day
)
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom function as here:

https://gorilla.bi/power-query/nth-business-day-from-date/

Cheers, Rick

Answer (score 0):

First populate Day column using calculated column

```
Day = FORMAT(WEEKDAY(Data[Date]), "dddd")
```

Then write a SWITCH function to add 5 working days using calculated column

```
Column = SWITCH(Data[Day], "Sunday", Data[Date]+5,
"Saturday", Data[Date]+6,Data[Date]+7)
```

Comment: That looks like DAX; won't work in powerquery